# How to convert E^x to Exp[x]?

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a string for example `"(E^Sqrt[x]*Sin[1 + Sqrt[x]])/Sqrt[x]"`, I want to convert `E^Sqrt[x]` to `Exp[Sqrt[x]]`.

Comment: Notice that `FullForm[Exp[Sqrt[x]]]` is `Power[E,Power[x,Rational[1,2]]]`

Comment: The tag [tag:expression-manipulation] might be approprite, too, but the question seems directly focused on manipulating a string, not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

This is honestly not an easy one to do in complete generality. String replacements can easily go wrong for complicated expressions, so it's best to use the WL formatting framework to typeset the underlying expression correctly.

The first thing you need, is to tell WL how you want to display the exponential function:

```
MakeBoxes[E^x_, StandardForm] := RowBox[{"Exp", "[", MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm], "]"}]
```

Next, interpret the string as an expression:

```
str = "(E^Sqrt[x]*Sin[1 + Sqrt[x]])/Sqrt[x]"
expr = ToExpression[str, InputForm]
```

> [image]

As you can see, you still have the 2D formatting from `StandardForm` in place now. To create a 1D string that preserves the `Exp` function, you convert the expression to the box form and then explicitly replace FractionBoxes with a linear format:

```
boxes = ToBoxes[ToExpression[str], StandardForm];
DisplayForm[boxes]
linearBoxes = ReplaceRepeated[
   boxes,
   FractionBox[a_, b_] :> RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", a, ")"}], "/", RowBox[{"(", b, ")"}]}]
];
DisplayForm[linearBoxes]
```

> [image]

Finally, you can turn that back into a string:

```
newString = ToString[DisplayForm[linearBoxes]]
```

> "(Exp[Sqrt[x]] Sin[1 + Sqrt[x]])/(Sqrt[x])"

## Edit

This idea can be generalised to other boxes that we need to define infix forms for. And while we're at it, let's also add some logic for when we need parentheses:

```
Clear[infixFormRules]
infixFormRules[list_List] := Flatten[infixFormRules /@ list];
infixFormRules[box_ -> op_String] := {
  box[a_, b_] :> RowBox @ Riffle[
     Replace[{a, b}, 
      arg : RowBox[{__, "+" | "-", __}] :> RowBox[{"(", arg, ")"}],
      {1}
     ],
     op
  ]
}
```

For example:

```
ToString @ DisplayForm @ ReplaceRepeated[
   ToBoxes @ ToExpression["(E^Sqrt[x]*Sin[1 + Sqrt[x]]+y^3)/Sqrt[x]+x^2"],
   infixFormRules[{FractionBox -> "/", SuperscriptBox -> "^"}]
];
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you Sjoerd Smit, this really hepls.

Comment: @UyLinux You're welcome. Keep in mind, though, that my last bit of code (that judges if we need parentheses) might not always do the right thing. It's probably best to include all parentheses if you need to be sure that calling `ToExpression` on the linear form gives the same expression again.

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```
StringReplace["E^Sqrt[x]*Sin[1 + Sqrt[x]])/Sqrt[x]", "E^Sqrt[x]" -> "Exp[Sqrt[x]]"]
```

Returns:

```
"Exp[Sqrt[x]]*Sin[1 + Sqrt[x]])/Sqrt[x]"
```